# NOT NULL constraint failed: owner_id in form saving

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am trying to make a form which allows users to upload a file (a plain text dictionary file). Here is my model:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
import uuid


class Dictionary(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%y/%m/%d')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is the form I use with it. I want to only expose the file parameter for users to set. The owner I intend to set from the request user:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from dic.models import Dictionary


class DictionaryForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Dictionary
        fields = ['file']

    def __init__(self, owner, *args, **kwargs):
        self.owner = owner
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my view code, which sends the post data, files, and user to the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from dic.forms import DictionaryForm

@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DictionaryForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dic/upload_success')
    else:
        form = DictionaryForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'dic/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my failing test code:

```
def test_can_upload_file(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='foo')
    user.save()
    self.client.force_login(user)
    self.assertEqual(Dictionary.objects.count(), 0)

    file = StringIO(initial_value='fake data here')
    response = self.client.post('/dic/upload', {'file':file})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The assert line is never run because an error occurs first. The error generated is in the view code, at `form.save()`. The error generated is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: dic_dictionary.owner_id
```

Two questions. How do I correctly set the owner value in the form so that this error does not occur? And why does the error occur on the `form.save()` line, since `is_valid()` should have checked that no errors would occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_valid()` only validates the fields that you specified in the form (in this case - `file`). The form is valid - but you get an error later on because the other model field constraints are not met when saving.

Passing the `owner` to the form isn't going to work because the form is not handling that field. Instead you need to add the `owner` to the model after the form has validated, but before saving it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DictionaryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dic/upload_success')
```

(Also remove the `__init__` method on the form).

Comment: I now get **UNIQUE constraint failed: owner_id**